# Converting Apex trigger to Apex class

Tags: class, methods, triggers, apex, custom-object

I have built a large Apex trigger that really belongs in a class, but I am not sure how to transition my code from a trigger to a trigger/class/method schema.

So my question: How would I migrate these triggers into a trigger/class/methods structure?

(This code could also use some bulkifying, so forgive the vain repetitions and excessive SOQL calls.)

**TRIGGER 1 OF 2**

```
trigger LC_Update_LD on LeadCompany__c (after update){
   for (LeadCompany__c LC: Trigger.new) {

        List<LeadCompany__c> LClist = [SELECT ID, OwnerId, Name, Lead_Count__c, Status__c FROM LeadCompany__c WHERE ID = :LC.Id LIMIT 1];
        List<Lead> LDList = [SELECT Id, OwnerID, Company, LC_Lead_Company__c FROM Lead WHERE LC_Lead_Company__C in :LClist AND isConverted = False];
        LeadCompany__c oldLC = Trigger.oldMap.get(LC.ID);

        if(LC.Lead_Count__c != null){
            // Update Leads Owner
            if(LC.OwnerID != oldLC.OwnerID) {
                System.debug('--*Lead Company Owner is changed*--');
                System.debug('**Old Owner :'+oldLC.OwnerID);
                System.debug('**New Owner :'+LC.OwnerID);

                String OldOwnerId = oldLC.OwnerId;
                String NewOwnerId = LC.OwnerId;

                //Logic to change lead owners
                for(integer i = 0; i < LdList.size(); i++){
                        LdList[i].OwnerID = LC.OwnerID;
                }
                update LdList;
            }       

            // Update Leads Company Name
            if(LC.Name != oldLC.Name) {
                System.debug('--*Lead Company Name is changed*--');
                System.debug('**Old Name :'+oldLC.Name);
                System.debug('**New Name :'+LC.Name);

                for(integer i = 0; i < LdList.size(); i++){
                        LdList[i].Company = LC.Name;
                }
                update LdList;
            }       

        }
    }
}
```

**TRIGGER 2 OF 2**

```
trigger LD_Update_LC on Lead (before insert, before update, after delete, after insert, after update){

    Set<ID> LeadCompanyIds = new Set<ID>();
    Set<ID> OldLcId = new Set<Id>(); 

    if(Trigger.isBefore){

        // For New Leads
        if(Trigger.isInsert){
            for (Lead ld: Trigger.new){

                // If no blank email, check blacklist
                if (ld.LC_Email_Domain__c != null){

                    // If domain not on blacklist, associate existing or create new
                    List<Blacklist_Domain__c> Blacklist = [SELECT Name FROM Blacklist_Domain__c WHERE Name = :ld.LC_Email_Domain__c];
                    if (Blacklist.size() == 0){

                        // Search for existing company
                        List<LeadCompany__c> lc = [SELECT ID, Name, OwnerId, Status__c, Domain__c FROM LeadCompany__c WHERE Domain__c = :ld.LC_Email_Domain__c LIMIT 1];

                        //If company exists, associate LD, change LD Owner, compare LC Status
                        if (lc.size() > 0) {
                            for(integer i = 0; i < lc.size(); i++){

                                // Associate Lead to Company
                                ld.LC_Lead_Company__c = lc[i].id;

                                // Change Lead Owner to Company Owner
                                ld.OwnerId = lc[i].ownerId;

                                // Compare Lead Status to Company Status
                                if(lc[i].Status__c != Ld.Status){

                                    Map<String, Integer> status_value = new Map<String, Integer>{
                                        'Open - Not Contacted' => 2, 
                                        'Working - Contacted' => 3, 
                                        'Working - Initial Meeting Scheduled' => 4,
                                        'Closed - Qualified' => 5,
                                        'Closed - Unqualified' =>1,
                                        null => 0
                                    };

                                    Integer LC_Status_Value = status_value.get(lc[i].Status__c);
                                    Integer LD_Status_Value = status_value.get(Ld.Status);

                                    //Set Lead Company Status
                                    if(LD_Status_Value > LC_Status_Value){
                                        lc[i].Status__c = Ld.Status;
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                            update lc;
                        }

                        // If no company exists, create new LC, associate LD
                        else {

                            // Create new company
                            LeadCompany__c nlc = new LeadCompany__c (
                                Domain__c = ld.LC_Email_Domain__c,
                                Name = ld.Company,
                                OwnerId = ld.OwnerId,
                                Status__c = ld.Status
                            );
                            insert nlc;

                            // Associate new lead to new company
                            ld.LC_Lead_Company__c = nlc.id;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        // For Existing Leads
        if(Trigger.isUpdate){
            for (Lead ld: Trigger.new){

                //Get old record values
                Lead oldLd = Trigger.oldMap.get(Ld.ID);

                // If no email, email is changed, or company left blank, check blacklist
                if (ld.LC_Email_Domain__c != null && (ld.LC_Email_Domain__c != oldld.LC_Email_Domain__c || string.isblank(ld.LC_lead_Company__c))){

                    // If domain not on blacklist, associate existing or create new
                    List<Blacklist_Domain__c> Blacklist = [SELECT Name FROM Blacklist_Domain__c WHERE Name = :ld.LC_Email_Domain__c];
                    if (Blacklist.size() == 0){

                        // Search for existing company
                        List<LeadCompany__c> lc = [SELECT ID, Name, OwnerId, Status__c, Domain__c FROM LeadCompany__c WHERE Domain__c = :ld.LC_Email_Domain__c LIMIT 1];

                        //If company exists, associate LD, change LD Owner, compare LC Status
                        if (lc.size() > 0) {
                            for(integer i = 0; i < lc.size(); i++){

                                // Associate Lead to Company
                                ld.LC_Lead_Company__c = lc[i].id;

                                // Change Lead Owner to Company Owner
                                ld.OwnerId = lc[i].ownerId;

                                // Compare Lead Status to Other Leads, Set Company Status
                                if(lc[i].Status__c != Ld.Status){

                                    Map<String, Integer> status_value = new Map<String, Integer>{
                                        'Open - Not Contacted' => 2, 
                                        'Working - Contacted' => 3, 
                                        'Working - Initial Meeting Scheduled' => 4,
                                        'Closed - Qualified' => 5,
                                        'Closed - Unqualified' =>1,
                                        null => 0
                                    };

                                    Map<Integer, String> status_name = new Map<Integer, String>{
                                        2 => 'Open - Not Contacted',
                                        3 => 'Working - Contacted',
                                        4 => 'Working - Initial Meeting Scheduled',
                                        5 => 'Closed - Qualified',
                                        1 => 'Closed - Unqualified',
                                        0 => null
                                    };

                                    List<Lead> Lds = [SELECT ID, Status FROM Lead WHERE LC_Lead_Company__c = :ld.LC_Lead_Company__c];
                                    List<Integer> LD_Stat_Values = new List<Integer>();                                
                                    Integer LC_Stat_Value = status_value.get(lc[i].Status__c);

                                    //Convert Picklist values to numbered list
                                    for(integer j = 0; j < Lds.size(); j++){
                                        LD_Stat_Values.add(status_value.get(lds[j].Status));
                                        }

                                    //Get Highest Picklist Value
                                    Integer LD_Stat_Val = 0;
                                    for(integer j = 0; j < Lds.size(); j++){
                                        if(status_value.get(lds[j].Status) > LD_Stat_Val){
                                            LD_Stat_Val = status_value.get(lds[j].Status);
                                        }
                                    }

                                    //Set Lead Company Status
                                    if(LD_Stat_Val != LC_Stat_Value){
                                        lc[i].Status__c = status_name.get(LD_Stat_Val);
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                            update lc;
                        }

                        // If no company exists, create new LC, associate LD
                        else {

                            // Create new company
                            LeadCompany__c nlc = new LeadCompany__c (
                                Domain__c = ld.LC_Email_Domain__c,
                                Name = ld.Company,
                                OwnerId = ld.OwnerId,
                                Status__c = ld.Status
                            );
                            insert nlc;

                            // Associate new lead to new company
                            ld.LC_Lead_Company__c = nlc.id;
                        }
                    }

                    // If domain is on blacklist, remove association, update old company
                    else {
                        // Remove company association
                        Ld.LC_Lead_Company__c = null;

                        //Update Old Company [HOW DO I DO THIS!!]
                        LeadCompanyIds.add(oldld.LC_Lead_Company__c);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    if(Trigger.isAfter ){

        // For Deleted Leads, add company to update list
        if(trigger.isDelete){
            for(Lead ld : trigger.old){
                if(ld.LC_Lead_Company__c != null)
                LeadCompanyIds.add(ld.LC_Lead_Company__c);
            }
        }

        // For Inserted Leads, add company to update list
        if(trigger.isInsert){
            for(Lead ld : trigger.new){
                if(ld.LC_Lead_Company__c != null)
                LeadCompanyIds.add(ld.LC_Lead_Company__c);
            }
        }

        // For Updated Leads
        if(Trigger.isUpdate ){
            for (Lead Ld: Trigger.new) {

                // For Converted Leads
                if (ld.IsConverted == True && ld.LC_Lead_Company__c != null){
                    //Find related Leads
                    ID AccId = ld.ConvertedAccountId;
                    List<Lead> LeadConvertList = [SELECT Id, LC_Lead_Company__c FROM Lead WHERE LC_Lead_Company__C = :ld.LC_Lead_Company__c AND IsConverted = False];

                    //Convert all related Leads
                    if(LeadConvertList.size() > 0){

                        for(integer i = 0; i < LeadConvertList.size(); i++){
                            Database.LeadConvert lc = new Database.LeadConvert();
                            lc.setLeadId(LeadConvertList[i].id);
                            lc.setAccountId(AccId);
                            lc.setDoNotCreateOpportunity(TRUE);

                            LeadStatus convertStatus = [SELECT Id, MasterLabel, IsConverted FROM LeadStatus WHERE IsConverted=true limit 1];
                            lc.setConvertedStatus(convertStatus.MasterLabel);                    

                            Database.LeadConvertResult lcr = Database.convertLead(lc); 
                            System.assert(lcr.isSuccess());                 
                        }
                    }
                }

                // For Unconverted Leads
                else {

                    // Get old values
                    Lead oldLd = Trigger.oldMap.get(Ld.ID);

                    //Check for Lead transfers
                    if(ld.LC_Lead_Company__c != oldLd.LC_Lead_Company__c){ 
                        if(ld.LC_Lead_Company__c != null){
                            LeadCompanyIds.add(ld.LC_Lead_Company__c);
                        }
                        if(oldLd.LC_Lead_Company__c != null){
                            OldLcId.add(oldLd.LC_Lead_Company__c); 
                        }
                    }

                    //Update New Lead Company
                    List<LeadCompany__c> NewLC = [SELECT Id, Name, OwnerID, Domain__c, Status__c FROM LeadCompany__c WHERE ID = :Ld.LC_Lead_Company__c LIMIT 1];
                    if(NewLC.size() > 0){

                        for(integer i = 0; i < NewLC.size(); i++){

                            //Update lead company owner
                            if(Ld.OwnerID != oldLd.OwnerID) {
                                    NewLC[i].OwnerID = Ld.OwnerID;
                            }

                            //Update lead company name
                            if(Ld.Company != oldLd.Company) {
                                NewLC[i].Name = Ld.Company;
                            }

                            //Update lead company status
                            if(NewLC[i].Status__c != Ld.Status){

                                Map<String, Integer> status_value = new Map<String, Integer>{
                                     'Open - Not Contacted' => 2, 
                                     'Working - Contacted' => 3, 
                                     'Working - Initial Meeting Scheduled' => 4,
                                     'Closed - Qualified' => 5,
                                     'Closed - Unqualified' =>1,
                                     null => 0
                                 };

                                Map<Integer, String> status_name = new Map<Integer, String>{
                                     2 => 'Open - Not Contacted',
                                     3 => 'Working - Contacted',
                                     4 => 'Working - Initial Meeting Scheduled',
                                     5 => 'Closed - Qualified',
                                     1 => 'Closed - Unqualified',
                                     0 => null
                                 };

                                 List<Lead> Lds = [SELECT ID, Status FROM Lead WHERE LC_Lead_Company__c = :ld.LC_Lead_Company__c];
                                 List<Integer> LD_Stat_Values = new List<Integer>();                                
                                 Integer LC_Stat_Val = status_value.get(NewLC[i].Status__c);
                                 Integer LD_Stat_Val = 0;

                                 //Convert Picklist values to numbered list
                                 for(integer j = 0; j < Lds.size(); j++){
                                     LD_Stat_Values.add(status_value.get(lds[j].Status));
                                     }

                                 //Get highest Lead Status
                                 for(integer j = 0; j < Lds.size(); j++){
                                     if(status_value.get(lds[j].Status) > LD_Stat_Val){
                                        LD_Stat_Val = status_value.get(lds[j].Status);
                                     }
                                 }
                                 //Compare Lead Status with Lead Company Status
                                 if(LD_Stat_Val != LC_Stat_Val){
                                    NewLC[i].Status__c = status_name.get(LD_Stat_Val);
                                 }
                             }
                        }       

                        //Update lead company
                        update NewLC;
                    }
                    //Update Old Lead Company
                    List<LeadCompany__c> OldLC = [SELECT Id, Name, OwnerID, Domain__c, Status__c FROM LeadCompany__c WHERE ID = :oldLd.LC_Lead_Company__c AND ID != :Ld.LC_Lead_Company__c LIMIT 1];
                    if(OldLC.size() > 0){
                        //Update lead company status
                        for(integer i = 0; i < OldLC.size(); i++){
                            if(OldLC[i].Status__c == OldLd.Status){

                                Map<String, Integer> status_value = new Map<String, Integer>{
                                     'Open - Not Contacted' => 2, 
                                     'Working - Contacted' => 3, 
                                     'Working - Initial Meeting Scheduled' => 4,
                                     'Closed - Qualified' => 5,
                                     'Closed - Unqualified' =>1,
                                     null => 0
                                 };

                                Map<Integer, String> status_name = new Map<Integer, String>{
                                     2 => 'Open - Not Contacted',
                                     3 => 'Working - Contacted',
                                     4 => 'Working - Initial Meeting Scheduled',
                                     5 => 'Closed - Qualified',
                                     1 => 'Closed - Unqualified',
                                     0 => null
                                 };

                                 List<Lead> Lds = [SELECT ID, Status FROM Lead WHERE LC_Lead_Company__c = :oldld.LC_Lead_Company__c];
                                 List<Integer> LD_Stat_Values = new List<Integer>();                                
                                 Integer LC_Stat_Value = status_value.get(OldLC[i].Status__c);

                                 //Convert Picklist values to numbered list
                                 for(integer j = 0; j < Lds.size(); j++){
                                     LD_Stat_Values.add(status_value.get(lds[j].Status));
                                     }

                                 Integer LD_Stat_Val = 0;
                                 for(integer j = 0; j < Lds.size(); j++){
                                     if(status_value.get(lds[j].Status) > LD_Stat_Val){
                                        LD_Stat_Val = status_value.get(lds[j].Status);
                                     }
                                 }

                                 if(LD_Stat_Val != LC_Stat_Value){
                                    OldLC[i].Status__c = status_name.get(LD_Stat_Val);
                                 }
                                 update NewLC;
                             }
                        }
                        update OldLC;
                        Set<Id> OldLCset = (new Map<Id,LeadCompany__c>(OldLC)).keySet();
                        LeadCompanyIds.addall(OldLCset);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    if(LeadCompanyIds != Null){
        List<AggregateResult> aggs = [select LC_Lead_Company__c, count(ID) LeadCount from Lead where LC_Lead_Company__c in : LeadCompanyIds Group By LC_Lead_Company__c];
        Map<Id,Integer> LeadCountMap = new Map<Id,Integer>();
        for (AggregateResult agg : aggs) {
            LeadCountMap.put(string.valueOf(agg.get('LC_Lead_Company__c')),Integer.valueOf(agg.get('LeadCount')));
        } 

        List<LeadCompany__c> LeadCompaniesToUpdate = new  List<LeadCompany__c>();
        if(LeadCompanyIds != null){
            for(Id LcId : LeadCompanyIds ){
                LeadCompany__c newLc = new LeadCompany__c(id=LcId);
                newLc.Lead_Count__c = LeadCountMap.get(LcId);  
                LeadCompaniesToUpdate.add(newLc);
            } 
        }
        update LeadCompaniesToUpdate;
    }

        // Update Lead Count For Old Lead Company
    if(OldLcId != Null){ 
    List<AggregateResult> aggsOld = [select LC_Lead_Company__c, count(ID) LeadCount from Lead where LC_Lead_Company__c in : OldLcId Group By LC_Lead_Company__c]; 
    Map<Id,Integer> LeadCountMap = new Map<Id,Integer>();
    for (AggregateResult agg : aggsOld) {
        LeadCountMap.put(string.valueOf(agg.get('LC_Lead_Company__c')),Integer.valueOf(agg.get('LeadCount')));
    } 
    List<LeadCompany__c> LeadCompaniesToUpdateOld = new  List<LeadCompany__c>();

    if(OldLcId!= null){
        for(Id LcId : OldLcId){
            LeadCompany__c newLc = new LeadCompany__c(id=LcId);
            newLc.Lead_Count__c = LeadCountMap.get(LcId);  
            LeadCompaniesToUpdateOld.add(newLc);
        } 
    }
    update LeadCompaniesToUpdateOld;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A best practice is to have a class to attend trigger calls for a particular Object.

i.e.

```
public class LeadTriggerClass {
    public void aMethodForTriggerInsert(List<Lead> newListFromTrigger) {
        // Include your trigger logic here
    }

    public void aMethodForTriggerUpdate(List<Lead> newListFromTrigger, Map<ID, Lead> oldTriggerMap) {
        // Include your trigger logic here
    }
}
```

and your trigger...

```
trigger LeadTrigger on Lead (include here all combinations... before, after etc) {
    // Instanciate your class
    LeadTriggerClass ltc = new LeadTriggerClass();

    // Call your methods depending of your needs... i.e
    if(Trigger.isBefore){
        if(Trigger.isInsert){
            ltc.aMethodForTriggerInsert(Trigger.new);
        }

        if(Trigger.isUpdate){   
            ltc.aMethodForTriggerUpdate(Trigger.new, Trigger.oldMap);
        }                   
        ....
    }
    ....
}
```

Hope that helps!